# Latest snapshot from gradle

Tags: repository, gradle, publish, snapshot

We are using gradle to publish **locally** and **remote** (nexus) to a **snapshot** repository (using the 'maven-publish' plugin). When I make a local build, I would like to use the latest snapshot version either from my local repository or the remote one. Now when gradle finds one locally the remote one is not considered anymore.

Is there a way to configure this or should I use other plugins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Gradle doesn't (as of 1.10) support getting the latest snapshot across multiple repositories. In Maven, this works (only) because the local Maven repo is treated specially, and a snapshot found there won't terminate the search.

Comment: Thanks, Peter thats a pitty. Do you know a workaround for this, or is the only solution not using the mavenLocal and always publishing to the remote repository?

Comment: There is no workaround that allows you to get the latest snapshot across repositories. Depending on your use case, there may be other solutions, such as building everything locally, which can be reasonably fast (due to Gradle's incremental build feature) and more reliable than mixing local and remote snapshots.